# Squidanalyzer error

Tags: linux, squid

I installed squidanalyzer-5.4.tar.gz, following this tuto http://squidanalyzer.darold.net/install.html and setting as recommandation but when I run http://testserver.com/squidreport I get error below :

You don't have permission to access /squidreport/ on this server.

Titi

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities squidanalyzer needs logs file to generate report for example here do

```
# cd /etc/squidanalyzer
# squid-analyzer /var/log/squid/access.log
# squid-analyzer /var/log/squid/cache.log
```

than check the above link you should definitely get the log online.

second thing is squidnanalyzer works based on cronjob. so might be crontab did not work for your system check crontab (make sure crontab need postfix to work).
so if crontab is not working would not automatically generate report.

Answer (score 0):

Either simple file system privileges on the directory are incorrect for web access, or, more likely, `/usr/local/bin/squid-analyzer`  has not generated any reports yet and the directory does not yet have a index.html document.

Check your webserver's error_log on the cause of the error.

Comment: I already changed '/var/www/squidanalyzer' to apache:apache, when I run '/usr/local/bin/squid-analyzer' manually , I got this output 'FATAL: pid file (/tmp/squid-analyzer.pid) exists, an other squid-analalyzer process may still running.' I already tried the same creating an index.html there but I got a blank page when opening http://hostname/squidreport. And apache's error log is hsowing this : '[error] [client 192.168.101.53] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/squidanalyzer/'

Comment: That 'Directory index forbidden' error is the result of a missing index document. Creating a simple index.html with some text should have made that text appear in your browser and resolve that error. As for the fact that squid-analyser is still running, please confirm if that's actually the case, otherwise remove the pid file and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Change the permission to squid analyzer location to chmod 644 -R /location-squid-analyzer

Also check the cache.log chmod 644 and no need of cache to change

make sure you given cache effective users in squid.conf with user you trying to access log files.